# How to set NavigationOptions of a parent?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, header, navigation, navigator

I have nested navigator in my app. I would like my header bar to be set on the root of the navigaton, so there will be a mutual header bar to all screens in my application.

my index.js is:

```
const StackOpportunityNavigator = createStackNavigator(
{
  MainOpportunity: OpportunityScreen,
  ClientScreen: ClientScreen,
  BusinessMapLocation: BusinessMapLocation,
  LoginScreen: LoginScreen
},
{
  initialRouteName: 'MainOpportunity',
  headerMode: 'none',
  transitionConfig: () => fromLeft(600),    
 }
);

const DrawerNavigationOptions = createDrawerNavigator(
{
   OpportunityStack: { screen: StackOpportunityNavigator },
   History: HistoryScreen,
   MyChances: MyChancesScreen,
   Info: InfoScreen
},
{
  contentComponent: (props) => <SideBar {...props} />,
  drawerPosition: 'right',
  transitionConfig: () => fromLeft(600),
 }
);

const LoginNavigator = createStackNavigator(
{
   LoadingScreen: LoadingScreen,
   LoginScreen: LoginScreen,
   DrawerNavigator: DrawerNavigationOptions
},
{
 transitionConfig: () => fromLeft(600),
 headerMode: 'screen',
 navigationOptions: {
   headerStyle: {
     backgroundColor: Colors.primary
   },
   headerTintColor: '#fff',
   headerTitleStyle: {
     fontWeight: 'normal',
     fontSize: 18
   }
  }
 }
);

export default LoginNavigator;
```

In every screen in my application i have this code:

```
static navigationOptions = {
      header: <HeaderBar title={'currentScreenTitle'} />
  };
```

However it works from 'LoginScreen' screen and all the others from 'LoginNavigator', but not from any other screen like 'History'.

How can i still control the  navigation options from other screen like 'History' and set the title, if my navigation header bar is in the most root navigator?

Hope you understand my question.
Really hope to for your answers as fast as possible.
Thanks guys!

Comment: Try `this.props.navigation.getParent.setOptions`: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-prop/#getparent

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand there is no way to access the parent navigator from within a nested screen.

The documentation states: "[You can only modify navigation options for a navigator from one of its screen components. This applies equally to navigators that are nested as screens](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-options-resolution.html)."

It's not very convenient but I think creating your own component is the only way to achieve this. There is a helpful library that will make creating your header component easier though. [React Native Elements](http:///https://react-native-elements.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/getting_started.html)

Answer (score 0):

I have been having the same issue what I did is made header null in navigationOptions and added my header component in screen as a regular component and performed all the logic, Its not the best practice but a work around :)

Comment: yes i did it too... but i really want to learn the best practice in coding, and i think i just miss some simple solution